# Evitar un ValueError dentro de un ciclo doble de funciones

Tags: python-3.x

Llamaré *secuencia* a la introducción de valores por teclado.
Al ejecutar el código y dar la secuencia [1,+,-,2] el código activa el `ValueError` dentro de la función estando en el módulo de Inicio. No entiendo por qué pasa eso: si se cambia la secuencia a [1,-,2] sale del código. La función de esto es que el `ValueError` no se active en la secuencia [1,+,-,2] para poder mostrar "Mas texto" en "Mas Informacion".
Cabe señalar que este código tiene un número de restricciones grande (*Lindo Profesor..*), además de que el código original tiene muchas más cosas (*Lindo Ejercicio..*). Para simplificar:

1. Solo se pueden usar `def` (funciones) para el codigo, nada de clases.
2. Está permitido el bloque `try/except`, solo bajo el uso de `ValueError`.
3. No está permitido usar **cualquier** keyword fuera de Programación I — Libro con toda programación básica, muy básica (`if`, `while` y poco más)—.
4. No está permitido el uso de Boleanos (True/False).
5. No se pueden usar importaciones o librerías externas (como el `import sys` para salir del código o el `math` (para otra función del ejercicio) o en resumen cualquier `import` o librería).
6. No se puede usar más de 1 bloque `try/except` por función .
7. Las funciones no pueden llevar o recibir variables.
8. No usar agendas o diccionarios.

Y otras más que cubren otras partes del ejercicio, pero lo general está ya establecido.

Aquí el código:

```
    def Inicio():
        try:
            print("Bienvenida")
            print("Opciones")
            print("Función / Salir / ...")  # Una vez regresado el modulo Funcion
            print("   1    -   2 - ...")
            n = int(input(":"))  # Aqui deberia de leer n y no validar nd del otro modulo
            # Al tomar el error de Funcion y no el de Inicio, entra en ciclo si se va por [+] y no se
            # puede "salir" ,Si se vuelve a ingresar [- y 2] sale del codigo, pero el error no deberia
            # de salir, por lo menos para la secuencia [1,+,-,2]
            if n == 1:
                Funcion()
            elif n == 2:
                while n == 2:
                    break
            elif n == 3:
                print("...")
        except ValueError:
            print("Valor Invalido Inicio!")
            Inicio()
    def Funcion():
        try:
            print("Bienvenida")
            print("Opciones")
            print("Caso 1 / Caso 2 / Salir / Mas información /...")
            print("   1    -   2   -  [-]  -       +         /...")
            nd = str(input(" : "))
            if nd == "+":
                print("Mas texto")
                print("Opciones")
                print("Caso 1 / Caso 2 / Salir /...")
                print("   1    -   2   -  [-]  /...")
                nd = str(input(" : "))  # Aqui declaro nd
                # En la validacion, si coloca [-] regresa al inicio
                if nd == "-":  # Si coloca otro caracter , activa el ValueError
                    print("Texto despedida")
                    Inicio()
                # Ya que si coloca otro caracter da ValueError, se valida por int.
                # Validando obtengo solo valores del caso 1 y 2
                while int(nd) < 1 or int(nd) > 2:
                    nd = str(input(" : "))
            # Dado que se coloca un valor que no active el while, se valida en 1 y 2
            elif nd == "-":
                print("Texto despedida")
                Inicio()
            elif int(nd) == 1:
                print("Texto 1")
                Funcion()
            elif int(nd) == 2:
                print("Texto 2")
                Funcion()
        except ValueError:
        print("Valor Invalido!")
        Funcion()
    Inicio()
```

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, aunque lleva a otro problema que no especifique, los "/..." indican mas numeros, siendo que usaria un while bastante largo, no se si exista solución para ello (para evitar hacer un while con muchas condiciones), ademas de que si aplico esto de las cadenas, de alguna manera el codigo termina al aplicar un numero incorrecto y despues uno correcto.

Comment: El codigo usa cadenas por una razón, el codigo original refiere a una calculadora, cada funcion son en realidad funciones matemáticas, si bien uso los numeros para los resultados, hay una especificación que incluye las cadenas, siendo que, mediante un caracter [+] u otro se pueda "expandir" el ejercicio dado, ya que si se toma en cuenta una suma, el resultado cubre cualquier numero (ya que usa valores siempre aleatorios), podria usar numeros negativos dentro del limite de operaciones del random como opcion, aunque si existe otra solución, seria mejor que colocar Salir "999" o Salir "-999"

Comment: Tu solucion es parecida a la que llegue, pero esta la condicion 4, que impide el uso de booleanos. Aunque debe de haber otra manera.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Inicio():
    try:
        print( "Menú principal" )
        print( "Opciones:")

           # cambié un poco el mensaje... me parece más claro
        print( "Ingresa `1` si quieres A\n `2` si quieres B...")  
        n = int( input( ":" )) 
        if n == 1:
            Funcion()
        # tus otras opciones
    except ValueError:
        print( "Valor Invalido Inicio!" )
        Inicio()

def Funcion():
    try:
        print( "Funciones" )
        print( "Opciones" )
        print( "Ingresa `1` si quieres calcular\n `2` si quieres B..." )
        nd = input(" : ")
        if nd == "1":

               # creamos dos listas donde guardamos los números y las operaciones.
               # con dato = "" nos aseguramos que el while se ejecute al menos una vez.
            valores = []
            operaciones = []
            dato = ""
            while dato != "$":
                dato = input(" : ")
                try:
                    numero = int( dato )
                       # si puede convertirlo, lo agrego
                    valores.append( numero )
                except ValueError:
                       # si no es número evalúo si se debe salir, agregar a operaciones o llamar a "calcular"
                    if dato == "$":  
                        print("Texto despedida")
                        
                    elif dato == "+" or dato == "-" or dato == "*" or dato == "/":
                        operaciones.append( dato )
                    elif dato == "=":
                        calcular( valores, operaciones )
            Inicio()
            
        elif nd == "-":
            print("Texto despedida")
            Inicio()
        elif int(nd) == 1:
            print("Texto 1")
            Funcion()
        elif int(nd) == 2:
            print("Texto 2")
            Funcion()
    except ValueError:
        print("Valor Invalido!")
        Funcion()

print( "Bienvenida" )
Inicio()
```

No pretendo que sea la solución, solo una idea que te ayudé a encontrar el camino ideal.
Queda pendiente la función calcular.

Comment: Probe a cambiar varias cosas y no encontre una solucion, tengo problemas en esto tratando de ajustarlo al problema: Si pudiera usar mas de 1 bloque try/except me facilitaria mucho mas cosas, pero.. (6.). Otra cosa es que no puedo definir funciones que manden o reciban variables (7.), el problema persiste a la hora de ingresar el segundo valor, ya que este no se valida (Para negativo), o de otra manera validar para que no exceda un valor x ( limitacion de random en rango (a,b)). Tambien uso "sumas infinitas", cosa que ya esta arreglada, pero falta validacion para 0 o negativos en division.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que da esta en `ValueError`, se deberia de trabajar ahí para empezar, limitando con un `if` y `while/break` en tu caso, haciendo que si se esta en el **Inicio** y se quiere salir, activa el `ValueError` de la **Funcion** y este rompe el ciclo saliendo del codigo.
Todos los caracteres que se puedan llegar a usar se definen en el `except` , los numeros no representan un problema.

Tambien en las limitaciones no se prohíbe el uso de funciones `def` dentro de la función por lo que se puede definir una o varias para almacenar textos grandes, pero  se deberá de llevar todas las validaciones a la nueva función, ya que no se permite el transporte de variables (7.).

Por último, no olvidar el orden de los `if` y `elif`, primero los carácteres y luego los números, si se coloca un `while` dentro de un `if` o `elif` para validar algo, recuerda mover el mismo orden dentro del `while` siempre y cuando lo necesites, lo mismo para otras funciones como el `for`.

Un par de advertencias a tener en cuenta:

```
Local variable 'nd' might be referenced before assignment
```

Para este no hay nada que hacer, ya que no esta permitido el uso cualquier `KeyWord` fuera de los comunes (3.), en todo caso su solucion seria declarar 'nd' como una variable global.

```
Shadows name 'nd' from outer scope
```

Recuerda renombrar las variables de ser necesario en los ciclos, ya que pueden causar problemas si se cruzan.

Aqui el código solucionado:

```
def Inicio():
    try:
        print("Bienvenida")
        print("Opciones")
        print("Función / Salir / ...")
        print("   1    -   2 - ...")
        n = int(input(":"))
        if n == 1:
            Funcion()
        elif n == 2:
            while n == 2:
                break
        elif n == 3:
            print("...")
    except ValueError:
        print("Valor Invalido Inicio!")
        Inicio()


def Funcion():
    try:
        def Funcion_Plus(): #Definimos una funcion extra
            print("Mas texto")
            print("Opciones")
            print("Caso 1 / Caso 2 / Caso 3 /Salir /...")
            print("   1    -   2   -    3   - [-]  /...")
            nd = str(input(" : "))
            if nd == "-":
                print("Texto despedida")
                Inicio()
            while int(nd) < 1 or int(nd) > 3: #Aqui se valida todas las opciones extra
                print("Ingrese en rango")
                nd = str(input(" : "))
                if nd == "-": #Recuerda siempre colocar caracteres antes que números
                    print("Texto despedida") #Solo en caso de necesitarlo
                    Inicio()
                if int(nd) == 1:
                    print("Texto 1")
                    Funcion()
                elif int(nd) == 2:
                    print("Texto 2")
                    Funcion()
                elif int(nd) == 3:
                    print("Texto 3")
                    Funcion()
        print("Bienvenida")
        print("Opciones")
        print("Caso 1 / Caso 2 / Salir / Mas información /...")
        print("   1    -   2   -  [-]  -       +         /...")
        nd = str(input(" : "))
        if nd == "+":
            Funcion_Plus() #Se llama a la funcion extra
        elif nd == "-":
            print("Texto despedida")
            Inicio()
        while int(nd) < 1 or int(nd) > 2: #Se vuelve a validar para el resto de opciones
            print("Ingrese en rango")
            nd = str(input(" : "))
            if nd == "+":
                Funcion_Plus() #Se vuelve a llamar en caso de que se active el while
            elif nd == "-":
                print("Texto despedida")
                Inicio()
        if int(nd) == 1:
            print("Texto 1")
            Funcion()
        elif int(nd) == 2:
            print("Texto 2")
            Funcion()
    except ValueError: # Definimos todos los carácteres que podrian dar un ValueError
        if nd == "-" or nd == "+":
            while nd == "-" or nd == "+":
                break
        else:
            print("Valor Invalido!")
            Funcion()


Inicio()
```